# im trying to find the volume of a shape but the definition is not working

Tags: python

i want the code to ask for the radius and length then the program will calculate pi*radius*radius*length from the definition area the print out the radius for example if at asks me the radius i put 5 same with the length it should say the volume is 392.75

```
def calculate_volume(radius, length):
    pi=3.142
    vol=pi*radius*radius*length



#main program
radius = int(input("enter radius: "))
length = int(input("enter length: "))
volume = calculate_volume(radius, length)
print("the volume: ",volume)
```

Comment: You need to return the result. You're not returning anything in your function.

Comment: `return vol` should do it

Comment: python has a library `import math` which has `math.pi` for more exact results

Comment: If you're coming from another language where "everything is an expression", and a function automatically returns the last expression in the function body, this can be confusing. In Python, everything is a statement, and a function that doesn't explicitly use a `return` statement will return `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement:

```
   def calculate_volume(radius, length):
        pi = 3.142
        vol = pi * radius * radius * length

        return vol
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is almost correct, you just haven't returned a result from your function!

```
def calculate_volume(radius, length):
     pi=3.142
     vol=pi*radius*radius*length
     return(vol)
```

When you put `volume = calculate_volume(radius, length)` right now `volume` is being set to `None` instead of `vol` from inside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet -- Get in the habit of using type hints - then use a decent IDE (such as PyCharm), or a type checker (such as MyPy). PyCharm would have given you a warning that you didn't have a return statement -- and anything calling your function would know the types of parameters and the return type.

```
def calculate_volume(radius: float, length: float) -> float:
    pi = 3.142
    vol = pi*radius*radius*length
    return vol
```